# find and replace a string in a file without using temp file with SED

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have a text file called sample.text which looks like this

```
Continent Lat/Lon: 46.07305 / -100.546
Country Lat/Lon: 38 / -98
City Lat/Lon:(37.3845) / (-122.0881)
```

I want to process this text to get output as follow without using temporary file

```
Continent Lat/Lon: 46.07305 / -100.546
Country Lat/Lon: 38 / -98
City Latitude: (37.3845) 
City Longitude: (-122.0881)
```

I don't have control over the values of latitude/longitude.

I have accomplished this using 2 awk scripts

```
BEGIN { FS=":"}  {print $2} | BEGIN { FS="/"}  {printf "City Latitude:%s\nCity Longitude:%s\n",$1,$2}
```

As I want to write the original file, is there any way to do it using

```
sed -i
```

All inputs are appreciated.

Comment: You mean like: `'s/City.*\(([^)]*)\) \/ \(.*\)/City Latitude: \1\nCity Longitude: \2/'` ?

Comment: @Sukminder. Yes it works  perfectly. Can you explain what you did there?

Comment: You need to learn regex (regular expression) learn step by step to be able to understand

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's,^City Lat/Lon:(\(.*\)) / (\(.*\))$,City Latitude: (\1)\nCity Longitude: (\2),' /path/to/file
```

### Explanation

- `sed -i 's,foo,bar,' /path/to/file`: do `sed` inplace, replacing `foo` with `bar`. N.B. I use `,` as delimiters here instead of `/`, so that I can use `/` in the string without having to escape them.
- `^City Lat/Lon:(\(.*\)) / (\(.*\))$`: find any occurrence of this regex, where `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of the line respectively, and each of the two `\(.*\)` represents a capturing group.
- `City Latitude: (\1)\nCity Longitude: (\2)`: replace with this string, where `\1` and `\2` represent the groups captured from the first expression, and `\n` is a newline.

Comment: What do you mean by '\1 and \2 represents the groups captured from first expression' ? Can you please explain for me that how these values are gettng generated .

Comment: @VineetSharma The second dot point will twice capture different strings `.*` with the escaped parens `\(...\)`. That is, the strings `.*` are matched as normal, and these strings are "captured", to be used later. In this case, they represent the latitude and longitude. Then, in the third dot point, we can re-use these previously captured strings, which will replace the placeholders `\1` and `\2`, which represent the first and second captured group respectively.

Comment: `sed` actually uses temp files. I am trying to deal with permissions issue about it.

Comment: @SalathielGenèse This answer was to a very specific question that requested the use of `sed -i`. You may want to ask a new question for your problem.

Comment: @Sparhawk Google lead me here, too, with the title of the question being "**(...)replace a string in a file without using temp file with SED**" but as `sed` creates a temp file this answer failing to solve that big question in the headline.

Comment: @luckydonald What you say is technically correct, so I was tempted to edit the title of the question to refer to sed in-place instead of preventing a "temp file". However, it looks like your answer interprets the question in this technical way anyway, so my edit would make your answer redundant. Having said that, your answer doesn't address this interpretation anyway. Also, IMO the fact that `sed -i` technically uses a temp file (probably) isn't the main point here, although the asker didn't respond to my answer, so it's unclear. Technically Linux uses temp files for everything (e.g. `/proc`).

Answer (score 1):

With `sed -i`, having truly in-place editing is **not possible**, as under the hood it actually is creating a temporary file for you anyway.

However, you can store the result for yourself somewhere and then write that to the file. A simple way is to use bash variables for that.

Just make sure your file is not too big. It should be fine for most files, but if you have a `69 GB` log file, maybe write it to `/tmp/` instead.

---

Change

```bsh
sed -i '<some regex>' --any-flags-you-want /some/file
```

to

```bsh
SED_RESULT=$(sed '<some regex>' --any-flags-you-want) && echo ${SED_RESULT} > /some/file
```